How to simulate Frame.NavigationFailed event being fired in WinUI app?
I would like to simulate NavigationFailed event being fired by the Frame instance to see how my application would behave but I am unable to achieve this.
I have checked the documentation (Frame.NavigationFailed, Frame.Navigate) where I could find information how to handle the event but no mention in which circumstances it is being fired by the framework.
In other words, I have to find a way to make Frame.Navigate method to return false. Based on the documentation I have to set the NavigationFailedEventArgs.Handled property to true in the Frame.NavigationFailed event handler - but I cannot force the framework to trigger the event.
I have tried to provide incorrect source page type argument into the Frame.Navigate method but it did not work as I would expect - the method just throws an exception instead of redirecting it to NavigationFailed event handler.
I have also tried to throw an exception from OnNavigatedTo event handler but the result is the same as above (which is actually expected, because this event is being fired after successful navigation).

Throwing an exception in the Navigated event handler should issue NavigationFailed.
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ContentFrame.Navigated += ContentFrame_Navigated;
    }

    private void NavigationViewControl_SelectionChanged(NavigationView sender, NavigationViewSelectionChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        try
        {
            var result = this.ContentFrame.Navigate(typeof(Page1));

            // Doesn't get to this line.
            if (result is false)
            {
                // Do something.
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            // Catches the NotImplementedException.
        }
    }

    private void ContentFrame_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private void ContentFrame_NavigationFailed(object sender, NavigationFailedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}

Unfortunately, setting e.Handled to true doesn't stop the exception so you won't be able to get the return from the Navigate method. I'm not sure if this is by design or a bug but I created an issue in the WinUI 3 repo.
